# Problem writing to a SQL Server 2005 Database from MVC2 App hosted on IIS6

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

As the title indicates I have an MVC 2 Application running on Server 2003.  So, I have IIS6 and a SQL Server 2005 instance on another machine that I am connecting to.

Here's the scoop:
--I have done the wildcard hack to get the MVC routing to work and the site loads correctly.
--I can read information from the database and everything displays fine.  (So MVC is working)
--I am using Linq to SQL.
--When I attempt to update data in the database I get an **internal server error**.
--The website runs correctly and will read and save information to the same SQL server instance when running from Casinni or IIS Express on my development machine.

Some other possibly useful information:  I am using Windows Integrated Authentication (the website sees me as the user correctly), the app pool on IIS is running as a user who has both read and write access to the database. I also currently have anonymous authetication turned off, but turning it on caused no change.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.  I feel like it's something really simple that I am just missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long hours on the phone with MS tech support here is the answer:

So if you have a database that contains two tables, both with automatic integer primary keys, and a relationship exists between a unique char field in one and a non-unique char field in the other, inserting new rows into the second table leads to invalid case exception.  This exception does not happen when calling to the database from Cassini, IIS7.5 Express or IIS 7.5 but does from IIS.6.0.

I restructured the database to avoid this design architecture and the problem was resolved.